# Is there anyway to make HTML printing properties cleaner?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I am finishing up the CSS for a form where a user inputs their information, and can export the form to PDF. The only problem I have is, everything looks very large and spacey in the input part when I go to export. The HMTL is fine on the browser, but when printing it is not returning the best results.

Are there any tips to make this fit on 6 lines instead of the whole page? I have attached what it looks like on the browser (left) and the printed results (right)[image: Screenshot of HTML page and printed results]

Here is my HTML and CSS for the HTML as well as print properties!

```css
.header{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

h1{
    font-size: 1rem;
}

table{
    font-size: 10pt;
}


@media screen {

    .wrapper{
        width: 90%;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    nav{
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    th,td{
        padding: 5px !important;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    /* Keeps table text centered like on old sheet  */
    input[bottom]{
        text-align: center;
    }

    textarea[bottom] {
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* Keeps top info centered like on old sheet  */
    input[top]{
        float: right;
        width: 150px;
        text-align: center;
        
    }

    textarea[division]{
        font-size: 13px;
        height: 70px;
        resize: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

    textarea[location]{
        font-size: 13px;
        height: 50px;
        resize: none;
        text-align: center;
    }


    input{
        width: 150px;
    }

    textarea[top]{
        float: right;
        width: 150px;   
    }
    
    .note{
        visibility: hidden;
    }


    
}
@media print {


        input {
            border: none;
            width: 100px;
        }

        /* Keeps table text centered like on old sheet  */

        input[top]{
            float: right;
            width: 150px;
            text-align: left;
        }
    
    
        /* Keeps top info centered like on old sheet  */
        
        textarea[division]{
            border: none;
            float: right;
            font-size: 13px;
            height: 70px;
            resize: none;
            text-align: left;
        }
    
        textarea[location]{
            border: none;
            float: right;
            font-size: 13px;
            height: 50px;
            resize: none;
            text-align: left;
        }





        
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP + JQUERY -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/record.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./js/record-of-transfer.js"></script>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        </nav>
        
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class = 'header'>
<form>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="p-2 flex-fill"></div>
                <div class="flex-fill">
                    
                    <h1><b><u>TRANSFER-OUT</u></h1></b>
                    <br>
                    <div><p><b>Date:</b><input id="date_out" type='date'  top required /></p></div>
                    <div><p><b><br>Department:</b><input id='department_out'  type='text' top required /></p></div>
                    <div><p><b><br>Division:</b><textarea id='division_out' type='text' top required division></textarea></p></div>
                    <div><p><b><br><br><br>Resp. Ctr:</b><input type='text' id='resp_out' top required/></p></div>
                    <div><p><b><br>Location:</b><textarea type='text' id='location_out' top required location></textarea></p></div>
                    <div><p><b><br><br>Property Control Office:</b><input id='prop_out' type='text' top required/></p></div>
                    <div><p><b><br>Department/Division Head:</b><input id='dhead_out' type='text' top required/></p></div>

                </div>

                <div class="p-2 flex-fill"></div>

                <div class="flex-fill">
                    <h1><b><u>TRANSFER-IN</u></h1></b>
                    <br>
                    <div><p><b>Date:</b><input id="date_in" type='date'  top required  /></p></div>
                    <div><p><b><br>Department:</b><input id='department_in' type='text'  top required /></p></div>
                    <div><p><b><br>Division:</b><textarea id='division_in' type='text' top required division></textarea></p></div>
                    <div><p><b><br><br><br>Resp. Ctr:</b><input type='text' id='resp_in' top required/></p></div>
                    <div><p><b><br>Location:</b><textarea type='text' id='location_in' top required location></textarea></p></div>
                    <div><p><b><br><br>Property Control Office:</b><input id='prop_in' type='text' top required/></p></div>
                    <div><p><b><br>Department/Division Head:</b><input id='dhead_in' type='text' top required/></p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="p-2 flex-fill"></div>

            </div>
      </form>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="window.print();return false;"/>EXPORT PDF</button>
    </div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```